# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT with google apis fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when I deploy my web project on client server I receive this error and pages load slowly.

```
GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

The browser gives me this error on Jquery javascript line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DART/static/assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

All javascript and css files are inside my project because behind the server the firewall blocks almost all external url.
I found this row into css, I should change with a local url.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic);
```

From [here](http://localfont.com/) I downloaded the fonts 
How can I import this in my project? Thanks

***RESOLVED***:

As GeorgeGkas suggested me, I added to my project the folder obtained from [localfont](http://localfont.com/), then I had to change all urls into font.css adding ../ before each url. For example `url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.eot');` has become `url('../fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.eot');`
Thanks

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: your firewall blocks external URLs. If you need it for your job, you should file a request to IT. Otherwise, you'll have to refrain from using Google fonts: as most of their services, they're intended to be used on-line and local hosting is probably forbidden in the licence terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want to import the font manually in your project. I recomend you to use [localfont.com](http://localfont.com/). Just Select your font and tick all the variants you like. The web app will generate a download link to a zip file that contains:

- a **fonts folder** with fonts format (.ttf, .woff2, .woff). *You don't need to play with those.*
- a `font.css` file that contains the `@font-face`s you asked for. Just copy paste it to your project and manipulate the `urls`m if you have to point in the fonts folder.

If you add you above question options in the website will get the bellow css file, as well as the fonts folder.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Light'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-300'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300/Source-Sans-Pro-300.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-regular'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-regular/Source-Sans-Pro-regular.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Semibold'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-600'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600/Source-Sans-Pro-600.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Bold'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-700'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-700/Source-Sans-Pro-700.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Light Italic'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-300italic'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic/Source-Sans-Pro-300italic.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Italic'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-italic'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-italic/Source-Sans-Pro-italic.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       local('Source Sans Pro Semibold Italic'),
       local('Source-Sans-Pro-600italic'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic/Source-Sans-Pro-600italic.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I thought, now I receive GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGCOFnW3Jk0f09zW_Yln67Ac.woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
Now I check for this

Comment: @luca download the zip folder. Don't use direct links. there is no need for internet connection with that solution as you donwloaded the appropriate files before and locally.